# xaml: insert DateTime with Hebrew Calendar

Tags: c#, xaml

```
class SomeObject
{
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to enter dates using the Hebrew calendar and a custom format instead of the default one in `xaml` , so that this code will be valid:

```
<SomeObject Date="א' תשרי"/>
```

Is there any way to make this possible ? maybe specifying the default Culture/Calendar globally ?

Comment: Add a second property which accepts an string instead of a date and then convert that to a DateTime and set it to the Date property